# how to hide an h3 tag until a reply is posted

Tags: php, html, tags

I have this:

```
  <h3 style="margin-left: 50px;">Reply From Admin:</h3>
  <p style="margin-left: 50px;width: 600px;" itemprop="reply">
      <?php echo $productReview['reviewreply']; ?>
  </p>
```

Now what I currently have puts a header above the Admin's reply so that the poster knows who is replying and the reply is stored in reviewreply. The problem is that the `h3` shows all the time even when there is no reply.

How can I hide that `h3` until a reply is issued? I cannot put the `h3` inside the `<p>` tag so please don't suggest it.

Comment: if this question is too broad.. then why is there a viable answer to it that worked flawlessly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there is a reply before trying to display it:

```
<?php if( !empty($productReview['reviewreply'])) { ?>
    <h3 ...>Reply from Admin:</h3>
    <p ...>...</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the solution, much appreciated